# frida -U -n "packagename" is giving a failure to spawn frida, unable to find process with the name

Tags: android, frida

I am trying to connect with frida to a certain application and its gives me the following error:

```
Failed to spawn: unable to find process with the name 
"com.androidpentesting.securestore"
```

This happens after i write this command:

```
frida -U -n "com.androidpentesting.securestore"
```

Can somebody help me out?

- the application is installed and is running on the emulator
- same frida version on both sides

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately for Frida the **Name** of an app is not the package name (called Identifier by Frida) but the label shown to the user.

You can see the app list and the app **Name** recognized by Frida by executing

```
frida-ps -Ua
```

Example output

```
 PID  Name      Identifier
----  --------  ---------------------------------
2799  Gmail     com.google.android.gm
2814  Messages  com.google.android.apps.messaging
2218  Settings  com.android.settings
```

So you have the choice to identify the app by it's name (`-n` parameter) or PID (`-p` parameter) but the package-name does not work.

Edit 2024-02: In recent Frida versions there is a new parameter that allows to attach to an app by it's package name: `-N packagename` or `--attach-identifier packagename`

Comment: i meant identifier that is shows when you use commend frida-ps -Uai
i chose the identifier from there to the related application and its prints the same error

Comment: @GuyGuy As I wrote you have to use the Name not the Identifier/PackageName

Comment: Oh my bad, anyway i tried and its gave me another error: 
      Failed to attach: process with pid 7906 either refused to load frida-agent, or 
       terminated during injection.
what do you think may cause it ?

Comment: @GuyGuy Some apps are hardened and refuse being debugged. Frida is in the end something like a debugger. You can try to start the app instead of attaching to a running instance. Hopefully that allows you to use Frida with that app.

Comment: i could use it before. its just suddenly stopped working. same result for every single app. and what do you mean by start the app instead of attaching to a running instance.

Comment: @GuyGuy On PC side you can use Python or JavaScript to modify the way Frida works. This way you can spawn/start the app using package name (app start in suspended state), then attach to it and resume the process. See for example the end of the following code which starts the app `com.example.test` https://gist.github.com/awakened1712/b68d9cdbd43e474812b9a3fec732d738

Comment: Well,I just changed from android studio to another emulator and its works again.
thanks for your kind help !

Comment: HUGE help, and not obvious, at least not to me.  Thanks very much!